# blazor SignInAsync have This Error 'Headers are read-only, response has already started.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, blazor-server-side

i make webpage by blazor
i have problem to login
and i use this normal code for login

```
    protected async Task LoginRegisterUser()
    {
        try
        {
            //if (Context.Response.HasStarted== false)
            //{
            //    await _next.Invoke(context);
            //}

                bool returnData = await CheckActiveCode(RegisterViewItem.PhoneNumber, RegisterViewItem.ActiveCode);
                if (returnData)//کد درست بود
                {
                    var usersItem = await userManagerService.SelectUserByPhoneNumberAsync(RegisterViewItem.PhoneNumber);

                    if (usersItem == null || usersItem.Id <= 0)
                    {
                        blazoredToast.ShowError("خطا در ورود کاربر");
                        return;
                    }
                   
                    var validatr = await signInManagerService.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(usersItem, usersItem.PhoneNumber, false);

                    if (validatr.Succeeded)
                    {
                         await signInManagerService.SignInAsync(usersItem, RegisterViewItem.RememberMe);
                        blazoredToast.ShowSuccess("کاربر در حال ورود", "خوش امدید");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        blazoredToast.ShowError("رمز ورود کاربر");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else//کد اشتباه است
                {
                    blazoredToast.ShowError("کد تایید اشتباه است");
                }

            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            blazoredToast.ShowError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

i know this code is true but blazor can not manage  Request HttpContext.

[image]

how can i use Invoke in this function ?

i use PasswordSignInAsync but not fix this problem and show again this error
'Headers are read-only, response has already started.'

Answer (score 3):

If you are using blazor server you need to create a razor page to login and logout because in blazor you must not access HttpContext ([Microsoft recommandation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-and-shared-state)

You have a sample [here](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-logout-page/) for logout but you can make the same for login.

You need just create a razor page and redirect from blazor to this page with `_navigationManager.NavigateTo("you razor page", true);`

in the razor page add the code :

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    await _SignInManager.SignInAsync(new ApplicationUser(){ UserName = "test@test.com" }, true);
    Response.Redirect("/");
}
```

You can also create a new razor project with authentication to show how it make it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here's the link to the [English docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-and-shared-state), since the edit queue is currently full.

Comment: In .Core 8, You can now use a Blazor SSR page with a form to get around this issue since it will be a regular POST

Answer (score 2):

In Blazor Server App, Context can not changes and it's read-only. as a result you must be develop middleware or implement your onboarding pages with razor and mvc controller.
for developing middleware please follow this link :
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13601

Answer (score 1):

The official document has the explaination:
SignInManager and UserManager aren't supported in Razor components.If you want to try with Identity,you should try with UserManager/Singininmanager in razor page parts
The document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

If you have futher issue,you could upload all of the codes  concerned so that i could test for you

Comment: `SignInManager` and `UserManager` are within ASP.NET Core Identity namespace. Your answer doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @Zimano, his answer makes a lot of sense. It clearly states that you can't access the HttpContext in blazor components because it runs outside of the aspnet core context pipeline (a crucial component to SignInManger and UserManager)

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the pipeline.  The server takes in a request for a page or other asset.

It then starts to form the outgoing page, including User information (user name and so on).  It sends this page (the response) out to the client.

AFTER that, it arrives at the Blazor rendering logic.  So either the client is or isn't logged in already, and there's nothing that you can do programmatically.  (well, there is, but it's not easier than just navigating to a login page)

When you try to log in from Blazor without making a new page request, further activities are NOT going through that pipeline, so there's no chance for the server to send the login info to the client.

Long story short-- you need to get the server to send a fresh page, and it can't (for the reasons I just mentioned) be Blazor.