# Difference between POST and GET for setting a cookie in Blazor Web Server Application

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, blazor

I am still a beginner with Blazor and I am still trying to make my very simple application create a cookie when the user enter some credentials using Identity and no Entity Framework, in my example infact I only testing the user with plain text values just for example.
So I created the standard server application and added all the configuration I needed into the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ClientApi",
    options => {
        var baseAddress = builder.Configuration["ApiSettings:BaseAddress"];
        options.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.PrimaryHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, c, ch, e) => true 
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddScoped(
    sp => sp.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("ClientApi"));    


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden";
        options.LoginPath = "/login";

    });
```

After that I added:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization(); 
app.MapControllers();
```

then I added the  to the top and bottom of app.razor and set up on the navmenu the authorized view for the forecast weather page.

After that I created a simple login form where the user set the username and password and I set up two bottons, one for testing the GET and one for testing the POST procedure.
Then I created a controller and assign to it two different route, one is reachable with the link /api/authg and the other is /api/authp for the post method.
The part with the GET is called with just this method:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/api/authg?pu={@loginModel.U)}&pp={@loginModel.P}", true);
```

and as soon as I click the button I get back to the index page and the cookie is perfectly created.
The Post button is calling a method like this:

```
private async Task HandleSubmitPost()
{    
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/authp", loginModel);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AuthenticationResult>();
        Debug.Print(result.Message);
        logindone = true;
    }
    else
    {
        var errorResult = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AuthenticationErrorResult>();
        Debug.Print(errorResult.Message);
        logindone = false;
    }
}
```

The controller code is the same on both path but on the POST one I return a OK or a BadRequest so I just post code here:

```
 public class AuthController : ControllerBase
 {
     [HttpPost("/api/authp")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticatePost([FromBody] LoginModel model)
     {
         if (model.U == "abc" && model.P == "def")
         {
             var claims = new List<Claim>
             {
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.U),
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "ADM"),
             };
             
             var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
             var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
             {
                 IsPersistent = true,
                 RedirectUri = this.Request.Host.Value
             };

             try
             {
                 await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 string error = ex.Message;
             }


             return Ok(new { Message = "Auth OK !" });
         }
         else
         {
             return BadRequest(new { Message = "Auth Failed !" });
         }
     }
}
```

The code and the request to the controller is working as intended but the cookie is not created. I suppose that the problem could be the first call to _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync that somehow stop the subsequent HttpContext.SignInAsync from the controller ?
Maybe it's stupid assumption but it's the only difference between the GET and POST testing procedure. If someone can help me to understand I will be gratefull, best regards.

**EDIT**
I did try to make the debug with cookie on the GET request and if I point to the localhost I could see only a cookie request but not response cookie, but it appears I am logged and authenticated normally. On Post it will not work as in your image @RuikaiFeng

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzQr8.png)

**EDIT 2**
So I did tried to check the solution Ruikai Feng suggest but just at the beginning I am already puzzled from the use of httpcontext, I did tried in my net core 6 application to do a Blazor page with the same code and receive a nice error about:

System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.

BTW I managed to create the cookie in a simple page that with a submit call the method in the controller:

```
  <form action="/api/auth" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

the method in the controller set up claims being passed to the:
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claims);
then a successive
return Redirect("/");
take me back to the login page with the cookie made, that could be fine but what I really want is this:
I pass username and password to a controller, the controller check the status of the credential on the database, after positive testing I create cookie and I would like to get from the controller at least an OK or a BAD result not just a redirect to the Index. But seems that the use inside the BLAZOR page of the HttpContext.PostAsJsonAsync prevent the controller to create and return a cookie at least I am guessing it.

Answer (score 0):

> The code and the request to the controller is working as intended but
> the cookie is not created.

Make sure your component is not interactiving with server via http instead of signalr (not in RenderModeInteractiveServer )

The picture below indicates how asp.net core set cookie:

[image]

From your codes it's httpclient instead of your browser send a request to server (When you try with NavigateManager,your brower do send a get request to api endpoint) and receive the response from server contains the `Set-Cookie` Header.Also, in .Net 8, you don't need to call an api, you could just handle the request within your component(In .net 7 or lower,you'd better login in a razor page)

An example for .net 8:

```
@page "/Auth"
@inject IHttpClientFactory factory
// you shouldn't enable interactive mode(via Signalr) here
@* @attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer] *@
@using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
@using System.Security.Claims;


<EditForm OnSubmit="Submit" Model="Input" FormName="Auth">
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText id="email" @bind-Value="Input.Name" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText id="password" type="password" @bind-Value="Input.Paswd" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
        <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
        
    </div>

   <button type="submit"> Auth</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public LoginModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    [CascadingParameter]

    public HttpContext httpContext { get; set; }

    private async Task Submit()
    {


        var claims = new List<Claim>
             {
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Input.Name),
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "ADM"),
             };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);


        try
        {
            await httpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

The cookie would be created as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment @Ruikai Feng, I am really new to the web development (worked mostly on winform) I am actually trying to implement it with Net 6 and I did infact tried too with razor page but manege only to make work it out only with a calling with a GET with a simple href with username and password set as parameter in the link.

Comment: The error :"System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started. " indicates the signalr connection has established,since you're interactiving with server via siganlr, the method related with httpcontext won't work,you could  call HttpContext.SignInAsync only in  prerender

Comment: You may check the document related:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor

Comment: And a related issue here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71785475/blazor-signinasync-have-this-error-headers-are-read-only-response-has-already

Comment: Yeah I read this page usually at least once per day but yet I never understand well this process about the httpcontext but that's because I am new in ASP.NET so maybe sooner or later I will make it work out.