# Blazor ASP.NET Identity auto log in with One Time Password: Sidebar and Logged In items are not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I'm working with Blazor and ASP.NET Identity to setup a one time password functionality.

I have my otp validated and then I make another razor page to do the actual sign in.

The problem is: when I navigate to the `/` page, my sidebar navigation and my information showing that I'm signed in is not showing up until I refresh the browser.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried to add some code on my index `/` razor page to do a refresh, but that did not work.

The normal Login.razor page works fine without doing anything directly after logging in.

I guess I'm missing a call to something to do a full post reload when I redirect?

I've tried this as well:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true);
```

Here is the code for OTPSignin.razor

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // Get the email from the query string
    var uri = new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri);
    var emailParam = uri.Query
        .TrimStart('?')
        .Split('&')
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.StartsWith("email="));

    if (emailParam != null)
    {
        Email = Uri.UnescapeDataString(emailParam.Split('=')[1]);
    }

    var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Email).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Check if the user is not null
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new PropertyNullException(nameof(user));
    }

    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false).ConfigureAwait(false); // isPersistent determines whether the session is persistent across browser sessions

    var nextPath = $"/?isreload=true";
    RedirectManager.RedirectTo(nextPath);
}
```

So it should go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I realized that the error has to do with this line of code:

```
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here is the error:

> blazor SignInAsync have This Error 'Headers are read-only, response has already started.'

And my redirect code was actually hiding the error.

```
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("redirectToIndex");
        }
    }
```

Full code:

```
@page "/Account/OTPSignIn"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.DataForm


@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IdentityRedirectManager RedirectManager
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@inject IAccountRepo accountRepo;
@inject IOTPUtilities otpUtilites;
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h1>Logging in...</h1>

@code {
    private string Email;
    private Guid OTPLoginId;

    private Timer? timer;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Get the email from the query string
        var uri = new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri);
        var emailParam = uri.Query
            .TrimStart('?')
            .Split('&')
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.StartsWith("email="));

        if (emailParam != null)
        {
            Email = Uri.UnescapeDataString(emailParam.Split('=')[1]);
        }

        var idParam = uri.Query
          .TrimStart('?')
          .Split('&')
          .FirstOrDefault(p => p.StartsWith("id="));

        if (idParam != null)
        {
            OTPLoginId = Guid.Parse(Uri.UnescapeDataString(idParam.Split('=')[1]));
        }

        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Email).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Check if the user is not null
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new PropertyNullException(nameof(user));
        }

        try
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71785475/blazor-signinasync-have-this-error-headers-are-read-only-response-has-already
            // do not like this fix, but it works and doesn't cause anything.
            // This allows us to log on and then invoke a redirect to the index page to update the sidebar razor page with the tree view menu and right toolbar items
            // to show the logged in user and logout button etc.
        }
        finally
        {
            await otpUtilites.CompleteOTP(Email, OTPLoginId, user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("redirectToIndex");
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm not sure how to handle the error:

> blazor SignInAsync have This Error 'Headers are read-only, response has already started.' System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpHeaders.ThrowHeadersReadOnlyException()     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseHeaders.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.set_SetCookie(StringValues value)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ResponseCookies.Append(String key, String value, CookieOptions options)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(HttpContext context, String key, String value, CookieOptions options)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleSignInAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties properties)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable`1 additionalClaims)     at Components.Pages.Account.OTPSignIn.OnInitializedAsync() in ## Heading ##\Components\Pages\Account\OTPSignIn.razor:line 67     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

I thought I just needed to redirect to another view, but that isn't helping because I still have the error.

If I catch the error, everything works fine.

Any new thoughts?